# Voice typing new line

Tags: voice-recognition, voice-command, google-voice-actions, voice-typing

I have a Samsung S9 running Android version 10 (q).
I frequently use the Google speech to text facility on the keyboard. I can make it do punctuation like commas and periods however I cannot make it do a new line or carriage return. 
There seems to be posts about very old Android versions showing that this may have been possible. is this still possible please?

Comment: Ok. Have you tried those old posts you encountered? Old does not mean obsolete. :-)

Comment: Ah good point. Yes I have tried them and it doesn't seem to work as it once did. Seems such an obvious functionality to have. I can't understand why it doesn't work now.

Answer (score 1):

On Android 12 with a Google Pixel 6 and Gboard voice typing, the voice command is "New line".

Answer (score 0):

I have the same phone, Samsung Galaxy S9, with Android 10, with the same problem. When I said, "new line" or "new paragraph," these phrases are not typed. If I say them after a period, a space is generated. If I say "period new paragraph," just the period is generated. Changing the language settings to single language or disabling, "Block Offensive Words" does not affect it.

In Google Play Store, I updated "Speech Services by Google" and rebooted.  After that I got, "new paragraph" to work.   I'm not sure if I didn't just get the pause to be an appropriate length. It works even without a comma or period.  It seems that it needs to be said as if it were written in italics.It doesn't always work.